# Acra and Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, acra

I have been using Acra in my android app with the google drive changes will acra still work .  Seeing as its a document number will drive keep the same numbering schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just work the same way.  Some discussion in the forums here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/acra-discuss

Comment: I can confirm that, until now, nothing has changed. ACRA is still working without any modification.

Comment: Let me know if it does change I too have some projects that really on it.  In fact you might be interested in these its related to healthcare and patient monitoring in real time.